# Hibernate creates redundant column in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, relationship, hibernate-mapping

I work at a room-management software in which I want to know the rooms in a certain building.

In the building entity the `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
   @JsonBackReference(value= "room")
   @OneToMany(targetEntity=Room.class, mappedBy="building", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = 
              CascadeType.REMOVE,orphanRemoval = true)
   public Set<Room> getRooms() {
       return this.rooms;
}
```

And in the room entity the `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```
@JsonManagedReference(value= "room")
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="building_number", nullable=false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public Building getBuilding() {
    return this.building;
}
```

And the auto-generated database generates an extra field because of those relationships and I just want them to be mapped on Room.building_number:

[building_building_number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHPi3.png) and I just need building_number.

Comment: your code seems correct, and it should only generate one column. Are you sure that the column is generated every time and is not a column that was generated with previous versions, and has remained? Could you delete it and see if it's recreated?

Comment: Yep, the column is recreated every time.

Comment: I've got some code exactly like that, and it works. The only diference is that I don't have the @OnDelete annotation, only plain JPA

Comment: Without @OnDelete it creates this column too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use something like that:

Building.class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="building")
private Set<Room> rooms;

// getters and setters
```

Room.class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="building_number", nullable=false)
private Building building;

// getters and setters
```